# Iteration on jsp page </c:forEach> clone results during iteration

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have problem with my controller Spring MVC and Iteration on jsp page. When I pass attributes on jsp page and try to iterate them, it is clone the results and view it on jsp page (results repeats everytime). Why it's happend and how to prevent it??

My form jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>   

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Страница выборки</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Выборка</h3>

<form name="extractForm" action="result" method="GET" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<b>Дата для выборки:</b>                <input type="text" name="particularDate"> <br>

<b>Имя учреждения для выборки:</b>      <input type="text" name="nameOfInstitution"> <br>

<b>Тип учреждения для выборки:</b>      <select name="typeName" size="1">
                                        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                                        <option value="MBOY">МБОУ</option>
                                        <option value="MBDOY">МБДОУ</option>
                                        </select>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Выбрать"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

My result jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>

<body>

<table align="center" border="1">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Наименование учреждения</th>
<th>Тип учреждения</th>
<th>Дата внесения данных</th>
<th>Режим дня</th>
<th>Режим работы</th>
<th>Очередность</th>
<th>Количество детей</th>
<th>Дети до 3-х лет</th>
<th>Дети старше 3-х лет</th>
<th>Дети пойдут в школу в ${creationDate.childGoSchoolDate}</th>
<th>Дети принятые в ${creationDate.childAdmissionDate}</th>
</tr>
</thead>    

<c:forEach items="${institutionAttrib}" var="institutionObj">
    <c:forEach items="${dateAttrib}" var="creationDate">
        <c:forEach items="${srcAttrib}" var="schRotChild">  

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>${institutionObj.nameOfInstitution}</td>
<td>${institutionObj.typeName}</td>
<td>${creationDate.particularDate} </td>
<td>${schRotChild.dayScheduale}</td>
<td>${schRotChild.workScheduale}</td>
<td>${schRotChild.rotation}</td>
<td>${schRotChild.numberOfChild}</td>
<td>${schRotChild.childUnder3YearsOld}</td>
<td>${schRotChild.childUpper3YearsOld}</td>
<td>${schRotChild.childGoToSchool}</td>
<td>${schRotChild.childAdmitted}</td>

</tr>
</tbody>

</c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>


</table>

<jsp:include page="index.jsp"/>

</body>

</html>
```

And my mvc method:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String SecondActionPage(@RequestParam String particularDate, 
                                       @RequestParam String nameOfInstitution, 
                                       @RequestParam String typeName, 
                                       Model model) throws Exception {


                if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution !="" && typeName=="") {

                    controllerSupportClass.findWithDateAndName(nameOfInstitution, particularDate, model);

                } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution =="" && typeName !="") {

                    controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDateAndType(typeName, particularDate, model);

                } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution =="" && typeName==""){

                    controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDate(particularDate, model);

                } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution !="" && typeName !="") {

                    throw new Exception("Search by choose all parameters is not exceptable");

                } else {

                    throw new Exception("You didn't put any search parameters");

                }


            return "result";

        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

did you confirm that the methods that are being called in your code are pushing correct data to the jsp page?

Comment: Yes sir. I guess so... If I would not pass data corectly it would just did not show me enything... Or What exactly you mean? Thank you.

Comment: by correct data, i mean you are not pushing same data multiple times which is then showed up on jsp page